# Trying to switch directories in Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am trying to switch directories in Azure but it prompts me to approve the request on the authenticator application. However, I have removed that entry from the authenticator application. 
[image]

When i try to sign a different way it still prompts me to use the authenticator app
[image]

Comment: Any other admins in that directory? They could reset your MFA info.

Comment: Have you tried to contact any administrators in your tenant? They would be able to help you re-register your MFA.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your Authenticator again going to: https://aka.ms/mfasetup but you probably need to have your AAD administrator Require re-register MFA again since you wont be able to login there without the MFA if you are not already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not set a phone number at the last step when you added the authenticator.

So, just as @juunas mentioned in the comment, you need to contact other admins to reset your MFA settings from Azure portal:

[image]